# How do I delete a git master branch on my terminal when there it is attache to my home folder and the repository on GitHub was deleted?

Tags: git, github, terminal

I created a git remote on my home folder (mac) by accident. I deleted the repository on Github thinking that it would clear everything but it did not. I can't seem to find how to delete it now. There is no other branches except for the master.[what I see on my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9xxZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete the hidden .git directory

simply open a terminal window and type: `rm -rf ~/.git`

i strongly advise using `rm -rf` with caution tho.

Answer (score 0):

A local `git` repository is just a regular folder, which contains a hidden `.git/` folder.

Delete the `.git/` folder from your home folder, and you will be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

remove .git repo from the working directory. (sometimes you might have initialized a git repository on your home directory, where all your changes might being tracked.)

Comment: You may want to provide instructions on how to do so (assuming a UNIX or UNIX-like environment)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).